# Slow directory listing on remote ExtremeZ-IP/SMB windows file servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac-osx, server-message-block, afp

I have Win2k8R2 file servers set up around the globe to distribute files using JAMF's Casper Suite to Mac OS X systems. However I've been noticing some very slow server responses lately. For example. From my terminal in the United states, I SSH to a Mac Mac in HongKong, I mount the AFP based file share from a server also located in HongKong. when I attempt to do a ls -la from terminal, the file list takes between 4 minutes and 11 minutes to display the result in terminal. When I mount the same share using SMB in stead, the time it takes to list the files is shorter, but still a lot longer than I would expect. The story is similar when I use Finder to manually mount the shares. I believe this slowness is causing erroneous errors to be captured in the Casper tools I use: "Could not mount share" and "File not found."

The Win2k8R2 servers themselves are not under load, CPU/RAM/Network or otherwise. Restating the server, or ExtremeZ-IP service does not have an affect. Neither does updating ExZip to it's current version (I am a few revs downlevel).

I've been using Resource Monitor to watch the network utilization on the file server during a directory listing (~1kbp/s) and a file copy from the very same directory (~256kbp/s).

Any advise would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Did you every find out what was causing this? We often have the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Sadly no... We've migrated our workflows to leverage https file transfers in stead of afp/smb.

Comment: Interesting, thank you so much for your reply. It seems like it might be a .DS_STORE issue where the connecting mac does not have full read write permissions on the file so goes into a loop trying to do it's thing. Still testing, but again thank you for the update.